# Magento 1.8 to 1.9 custom module

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.8

I have tried this [tutorial](http://istockphp.com/magento/adding-custom-page-to-the-customer-account-dashboard/) and it works on 1.8 but when i tried to copy module to version 1.9 not works! It's normal?

What are the changes that i have to do for this module in 1.9?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has no difference, which can be is the theme, checks if it is the same theme in both, and if are the same pages of **template** and **layout**, that you are adding or editing.

After update the cache and the index and test.

Comment: Thank you! if I want to use the module in another theme just me copy the module directories to the theme directory?

Comment: Yes, however the templates may use different forms, ai will need you to analyze, sometimes do not have the same file on another template because it is used in a different way.

Comment: You will need only understand the other template to adapt.